# Query on Email Content/Email body

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql, automationstudio, email-studio

Do anyone have any idea how we can query on email body/email content ?

I've a use case where I want get all the email name in which I've used a certain number 878XXX784741 and have sent those emails to subscribers.

I thought first if that number would be used in href tag, so I should query _Click data view and through linkname or URL field I hope I can get the result. But no luck!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finally able to achieve this through below solution.

Method : POST

URL:https://[your_domain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/query

Body :

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "leftOperand":
        {
            "property":"content",
            "simpleOperator":"mustcontain",
            "value":"[878XXX784741]"
        },
        "logicalOperator":"AND",
        "rightOperand":
        {
            "property":"assetType.name",
            "simpleOperator":"equal",
            "value":"htmlemail"
        }
    },

    "sort":
    [
        { "property":"id", "direction":"ASC" }
    ],

    "fields":
    [
        "enterpriseId",
        "memberId",
        "thumbnail",
        "category",
        "content",
        "data"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by doing REST API call to the `GET /asset/v1/content/assets` endpoint and then adding on top either [Simple Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetSimpleQuery.htm) or [Advanced Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm) to filter the results based on your need.

In your case, it is going to look something like that with the only condition: Content has "878XXX784741" -

```
https://[your_domain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=Content%20like%20'878XXX784741'
```

Comment: Hey @Niko - Thanks for the solution, but I'm not getting the exact number what I want. It's giving matching with 1st 4 digit of number. I'm getting huge results due to that. I want exact number to be searched used in emails. How can I filter that?

Comment: You can try doing an Advanced Query with a more specific search to narrow down the results.

Comment: Hey @Niko - Thanks for the suggestion and solution provided. But now I've achieved this through doing query in body not passing through URL. Please find my updated answer on this question

Comment: Hey, @darkCloud that is what is called Advanced Query and I was referencing it in my answer and comment above, so you basically did what I suggested to you from the very start.

Comment: Hi @Niko - Yes I tried the one that you suggested, although I was not comfortable how should I use advance query.. but read some post and article then got to know how it works. But really thanks for the suggestion and comment :)